# Is there a better way to assign multiple css classNames to React components?

Tags: javascript, css, class, reactjs

**I'm using css modules and at the moment my method for assigning multiple classes to components is:**

`` import {class1,class2 } from './styles.css'
<div><Link to = 'auth' className= {[`${class1} ${class2}`]} >Login</Link></div> ``

**this just doesnt seem efficient nor elegant.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use classnames (as mentioned by official react documentation)

link to github : https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

```
const class = {class1:true,class2:onlyIfFalgisTrue};
```

then you can use it as

```
<div><Link to = 'auth' className= {class} >Login</Link></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a utility called classnames 
https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

```
classNames('foo', 'bar'); // => 'foo bar'
classNames('foo', { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
classNames('foo', { bar: true, duck: false }, 'baz', { quux: true }); // => 'foo bar baz quux'
```

For your specific usage

```
const klassNames = classNames(`${class1} ${class2}`);
div><Link to = 'auth' className= {klassNames} >Login</Link></div>
```

I agree you might say this is the same as your previous code but see if want to add classes based on some conditions this is highly beneficial

Another Example

```
const klassNames = classNames(`${class1}`, {
`${class2}`: someCondition === true,
`${class3}: someCondition === false
}
```

I am using in my large react project really solves if else conditioning for classes

Example

Comment: can you post an example, i tried to follow docs but still unclear